# WCF Soap Format

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm developing a WCF Service that is going to be used by a government agency.
As they will access the same service hosted by different contracting companies, they have specified the exact way that messages **must** look like (so, they will only change URL's to access each company's service).

So, for this method:

```cs
sbyte Execute(int Id1, short Id2, string Id3, string Id4, string Value)
```

They expect us to accept exactly the following SOAP message:

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http:/
/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/
XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <m:Execute xmlns:m="http://tempuri.org/">
            <m:Id1>1</m:Id1>
            <m:Id2>2</m:Id2>
            <m:Id3>3</m:Id3>
            <m:Id4>4</m:Id4>
            <m:Value></m:Value>
        </m:Execute>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And our response must be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ExecuteResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <ExecuteResult>
                <res>0</res>
            </ExecuteResult>
        </ExecuteResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Right now, the messages for my current service, with binding="basicHttpBinding" and  using my test client (and also, WCF Test Client tool), looks like this:

Request:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ISomeService/Execute</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <Execute xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Id1>0</Id1>
      <Id2>0</Id2>
      <Id3>0</Id3>
      <Id4>0</Id4>
      <Value>0</Value>
    </Execute>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Response:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <ExecuteResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ExecuteResult>1</ExecuteResult>
    </ExecuteResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So, **my question is**:
What should I change, to make my service use SOAP messages like

"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP- ... >   <SOAP-ENV:Body>"

instead of using...

<s:Envelope .... >   <s:Header />

I have tried several bindings, custom configurations, and so on, but I couldn't make it look the same.

This is my current config, using the proposed customBinding:

```xml
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Test.SomeService">
        <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Soap11Binding"
          contract="Test.ISomeService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="Soap11Binding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport allowCookies="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any clues anyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the binding for your WCF service to `basicHttpBinding`, which uses `SOAP v1.1`, while `wsHttpBinding` uses `SOAP v1.2`.

See here: [`SOAP 1.1`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383490) vs [`SOAP 1.2`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part0-20070427/#L1165)

You can also create your custom binding and specify explicitly that your want `SOAP 1.1`:

```
<customBinding>  
    <binding name="Soap11Binding">  
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">  
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"  
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />  
        </textMessageEncoding>  
        <httpTransport allowCookies="true" />  
    </binding>  
</customBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried basicHttpBinding, as I stated above, but the default output from basicHttpBinding is formatted as the second set of Request/Reponse I posted.  I need the output to be like the first set.

Comment: @Modesto: Can you post how your response/request pairs look with `basicHttpBinding`?

Comment: I just tried with the customBinding you offered (used both in host and client). But I get the same message moving.

Comment: @Modesto: But that can't be. Can you please update your question with the service configuration (binding, service and endpoint)? Something must be going wrong.

Comment: Thanks by the way.So far, I could only recreate the requested format, using an .ASMX Service, but not using WCF (I don't know if it's even possible)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom message encoder to format the message to be exactly the way you need it. This is a URL for how to implement it : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx

In the WriteMessage method you can do the changes needed to the message.

Comment: This is a brutal answer, but it looks like the right one. Creating a custom format for WCF is not easy!

Answer (score 0):

For a complete control over the response in wcf, You need to use [MessageContract].

[MessageContract] are simple classes, which are further used as a SOAP packet for transmission.

By considering your requirement, you need to use MessageContract.